Cant remember title of movie simliar to journey to the center of the earth
Im trying to remember the name of a movie I saw a few years back. It might be from the 90s or the 2000s.
It was one of those journey to the center of the earth copies but there was a ship of some kind and some tablets that were magnetic or something. At the end of the movie, one of the explorers who was there before tried to get the tablets from the ship while its moving and falls into a volcano. I also remember  that he used some kind of machine to stay alive it looked like a capsule of some kind with tubes running into it. sorry I don't have more info its been a few years.

I finaly found the movie I was looking for Journey To The Center Of The Earth (1993) I think it was a made for tv movie that was supposed to be a pilot
https://edinburghfilmcritic.wordpress.com/2007/03/12/journey-to-the-center-of-the-earth-1993/
Thanks very much to all who tried to help

I believe it is "Journey to the Center of the Earth" from 2008, starring Brendan Fraser and Josh Hutcherson playing his nephew.
In one of the the message boards, there is a line that says

"12. Floating magnetic rocks are fine for walking on, but if a piece
  breaks off all of a sudden gravity will pull the broken piece down."

I remember the scene(s) with the tablets, when one of the characters would hop from one to another they would become unstable, but when they got to the exact center of the earth everything came to a standstill because of the lack of a magnetic field (if memory serves me right)

I remember the tablet scene from that movie, but there was no ship or capsule... :P

It could be The Core, starring Hillary Swank and Aaron Eckhart.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298814/?ref_=nv_sr_1

I've seen both of those movies but the one im thinking of came out a few years earlier. The tablets im speaking about were small and had markings on them. and could be held in the hand, It was an expedition of some kind with a digging machine that hey used to travel in.  They were looking for explorer who came before them.  You don't really see him until the end of the movie he spends most of his time in something like a coffin which was some kind of life support system it had tubes in it.  towards the end of the movie he jumps on the windshield of the ship and falls in some lava

@tperez2 then I am really at a loss. That doesn't sound familiar to me at all.
